# Reversing the order of a for loop output

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am currently writing a task where the user will input a number and it'll output a number of "*" depending on the number. Eg if the user inputted a 5, the answer would be:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number;
char star = '*';

int main()
{
    cout << "Input a number between 1 and 10" << endl;

    cin >> number;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < number; j++)
        {
            cout << star;
        }
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the number 5 was inputted, this would output:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

How would I go about reversing the order so that it is ascending order rather than descending.

Comment: Like this `for (int i = number - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: consider to move everything from the inner loop to a function `void inner_loop(int i)` then find the transformation for `i` that makes the same function do the same in reverse order

Comment: Your code outputs one extra `*` in each line.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the for loop in descending instead of ascending order.

**Example:**

```
cout << "Input a number between 1 and 10" << endl;
cin >> number;

for (int i = number -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = i; j < number; j++) {
        cout << star;
    }
    cout << "*" << endl;
}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by just reversing the order of the change of `i`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number;
char star = '*';

int main()
{
    cout << "Input a number between 1 and 10" << endl;

    cin >> number;

    //for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    for (int i = number - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < number; j++)
        {
            cout << star;
        }
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(Just how to reverse the order of the change of `i` is shown. The output of this program is not as expected.)

My preference is using `i` as the number of stars to print and avoiding using gloval variables and `using namespace std;`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number;
    char star = '*';

    std::cout << "Input a number between 1 and 10" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> number;

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            std::cout << star;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go from `number` all the way down instead of up:

```
for (int i = number; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
    {
        cout << star;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `j<number` use `j<i` and instead of `j=i` use `j=0`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number;
char star = '*';

int main()
{
    cout << "Input a number between 1 and 10" << endl;

    cin >> number;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {    
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            cout << star;
        }
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the second 'for' loop condition, in your function --

From,

```
for (int j = i; j < number; j++)
```

Change it to ,

```
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to achieve what you want. You can insert everything inside and array and print the array backwards, insert everything inside an array (starting from last position) and then print it in natural order, you can do it only by using indexes (like i and a lot of other persons did here). I also added a little input check, and put the code in functions for clearness:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number;
char star = '*';

void version1();
void version2();

int main()
{
    cout << "Input a number between 1 and 10" << endl;
    cin >> number;
       
    while(number < 1 || number > 10)
    {
        cout << "I SAID BETWEEN 1 AND 10, IS EASY, RIGHT?" << endl;
        cin >> number;
    }

    version1();
    version2();    

    return 0;
}

void version1()
{
    cout <<"Version 1: "<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < number; j++)
        {
            cout << star;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void version2()
{
    cout << "Version 2: (only by using indexes)" << endl;

    int cap_index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cap_index = i + 1;
    
        for (int j = 0; j < cap_index; j++)
        {
            cout << star;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

btw this is a more serious (and simple) way to check input:

```
do
{
    cout << "Input a number between 1 and 10" << endl;
    cin >> number;
}while(number < 1 || number > 10);
```

In my case i put it this way:
starting from 0 print '*' up to i + 1 times, this way you have an ascending order print:

- first time (from 0 to 1) print '*' -> print once
- second time (from 0 to 2) print '*' -> prints twice
- and so on up to the inserted number

Obviously this isn't not the best way to do this nor the most elegant, like in nearly every situation there are a lot of possibilities.

ps. i'm not sure, but you have an error in your code, as it prints a '*' more, each time, i don't know how is your output like that

Answer (score 0):

By using a `std::string`, you can avoid the need of an explicit inner loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int number;
    char star = '*';
    std::cout << "Input a number between 1 and 10" << "\n";
    std::cin >> number;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::string (i+1, star) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```